# Export to XML from CSV Laravel-Excel

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) (version-3) to import/export data into various formats. But i'm having trouble while exporting to XML. When i'm exporting to xml the following error occurring `No writer found for type Xml`. I'm not getting any clue or resources to solve this problem. Exporting to other format (csv, xlsx) working fine. Can anyone help me out with this one! Thank You.

Here is my code: 
In Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Exports\LoanInfoExport;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function storeLoanInfo(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->file('upload_loan_info')->getRealPath();
        $data = \Excel::toArray('', $path, null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::TSV)[0];

        $loanInfoForExport = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $disbursedValue = str_replace(',', '', $value[6]);
            $outstandingValue = str_replace(',', '', $value[7]);

            if (!empty($value[1])) {
                array_push($loanInfoForExport, [
                    'disbursed_date' => $value[0],
                    'borrower' => $value[1],
                    'loan_product' => $value[2],
                    'loan_id' => $value[3],
                    'interest' => $value[4],
                    'duration' => $value[5],
                    'disbursed' => $disbursedValue,
                    'outstanding' => $outstandingValue,
                    'status' => $value[8],
                ]);
            }
        }

        return (new LoanInfoExport($loanInfoArray))->download('invoices.xml', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XML);

    }
}
```

Then LoanInfoExport.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;

class LoanInfoExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithStrictNullComparison
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return collect($this->data);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

My intention is to read csv files and convert it to XML. So if anyone have better option for that, you can suggest it too.

Comment: do you have the php-xml extention? in your php configration?

Comment: I dont know, How do i check it! @ShaielndraGupta

Comment: or how do i install it in windows 10, xampp server!

Comment: to check this go to index.php ena d add this line at the top `phpinfo()`;die;` and share the output

Comment: https://ibb.co/CmQX7dD Here is screenshot from phpinfo of my xml related info and here is my basic php info https://ibb.co/m8WsrzR

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta bro.. can you help me out with this one?

Comment: You can only import XML file, exporting XML file is not supported yet please check this issue:
https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1860

Comment: @AhmedAlBermawy if you check version 3.0 export formats, there is a option for xml export.
By the way thanks for your response, I used DOMDocument to solve my needs!

Comment: Hey, I am now facing the same problem. Can you share your solution which you used. I have been able to export the csv file. It would be really nice if you can share the solution which takes in the csv variable and outputs the xml file.

Comment: @risingStark i can send you the file if you give me your email/any sort of contact address!

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed Well I can give you my email but you can also post it here as an answer to your question. It will help others in the future. Email - codingfever43@gmail.com

Comment: sent you an email